# adding a number using sql

Tags: php, sql, select, numbers, addition

This is what I'm trying to do.
If a person buys a lamp, `product_quantity` will go up by 1.
Another person buys the same product but the 'product_quantity' is 3.
So if total up its 4.

This is my code:

```
// build SQL statement to select how many quantities of that product.
$query = "select product_quantity from table where order_item_name = '$ordername' and order_id='$orderid'";

// execute SQL statement
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));

// shows how many quantity of that product
while($row= mysqli-fetch_assoc($result)){
    $lol = $row['product_quantity']
}
```

But how do I add this number to an existing number in the table using SQL?
For example, in this table, there's a field called `total_order`: 10.
I want to add the new orders: quantity 1 and 3 to the existing `total_order`: 10 of the same product to make it 14.

Comment: YOu have to add the update query to update the Quantity in Database.

Comment: but if i update 1 to total_order, wont the total_order be updated to '1' not '11'?

Comment: Try `"update table set product_quantity = product_quantity + 1 where order_item_name = '$ordername' and order_id='$orderid'"`

Answer (score 0):

Using any mathematical operations on a database column can be achieved by using the name of the column, the operation, and the variable (ex: UPDATE TABLE SET COLUMN = COLUMN (+-*/) $variable WHERE 1;)

```
$ordername = 'lamp';
$orderid = 1;

$total_quantity = 0;
while($row= mysqli->fetch_assoc($result)){
    $total_quantity += $row['product_quantity'];
}    
$sql = "UPDATE TABLE SET `product_quantity`= product_quantity + $total_quantity WHERE `order_item_name` = '$ordername' AND `order_id`='$orderid'";
```

Comment: but if there's a while loop like my example above to get the quantity of each of the orders of that product. how do i add them up?

//total quantity of lamp ordered
$total_quantity= $lol + $lol; ?

Comment: I've updated the coding portion to be more adequate with your situation.